# Tehillim 119:98 - interesting interpretation. Source?

Tags: sources-mekorot

> מֵאֹיְבַי תְּחַכְּמֵנִי מִצְוֺתֶךָ כִּי לְעוֹלָם הִיא־לִי׃
>
> Thy commandments make me wiser than my enemies: for they are ever with
> me.

[Tehillim 119:98](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.119.98?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

I recently heard Rabbi YY Jacobson using this pasuk to defend the idea that we can learn that, given our enemies are always really dark and evil, like Hitler, it must mean that the Torah we are entrusted to teach the world is full of light and goodness, to the equal and opposite degree:

> "I learn about your mitzvot [i.e. how light and good they are] from my
> enemies"

I can't find any commentaries that use this pasuk this way - is anyone aware of any?

Comment: דיני יצחק ניוטן ג?

Comment: I find this idea a bit odd - isn't there a principle that a small amount of light chases away a vast amount of darkness?  Surely that means that the Torah is far greater than the evil?

Comment: @MosesSupposes that it is a lower bound would fit with the pasuk. Also Don't know if the evil of Hitler is included in your mashal. There are two types of darkness.

Comment: Well as Terry Pratchett said, it is better to light a flamethrower than curse the darkness

Comment: Not exactly the same, but related: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/3316117/jewish/8-Nissan.htm

Comment: If YY is actually saying this, he is making the same mis-translation as Sefaria does. The pronoun היא from לעולם היא-לי is feminine singular and is referring to the Torah, not  (the plural) Your commandments מצותך. The connection of Torah to 'light' is from the saying of our Sages, נר מצוה ותורה אור. The "enemies" David is referring to here are Doeg & Achitophel. See Avot 6:3 and Sanhedrin 10:2.

Comment: See also https://chabadlibrary.org/books/magid/ot/45/268.htm

Comment: See also https://www.sefaria.org/Kedushat_Levi%2C_Genesis%2C_Noach.6?lang=bi

Comment: @YaacovDeane I don't see why his interpretation needs to utilise the second half of the pasuk at all, nor do I see the connection to Doeg and Achitofel as an exclusive interpretation necessarily. However that's all I could find which is why I am asking if he has another source or reference? Shmosel thanks for the very relevant connections

Comment: Similarly https://www.sefaria.org/Zera_Kodesh%2C_On_Torah%2C_Vayera.1